# Date formatting in Google Sheets is not working according to the instructions

Tags: date, google-sheets, formatting

Yes, I know; this question has been asked thousands of times in hundreds of different places, but Google Sheets stubbornly refuses to let me convert a date such as "9/18/2004" to "2004-9-18". I select one or more cells whose date format is "dd/mm/yyyy", click on FORMAT, then NUMBER, then MORE FORMATS, then I select "More date and time formats", and then select the example "1930-08-05", and then nothing happens. Nothing changes. I need help with this. Here is a link to the problem column:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gYdPcNO-Jq1SFUpdb88o7KKVqG5_ia9NpD_3T98CkEw/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

From Google:

Change locale and time zone
When you change the locale and time zone of a spreadsheet, it changes the spreadsheet’s default currency, date, and number formatting.

1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
2. Click File and then Spreadsheet settings.
3. Under "General," click the "Locale" and "Time zone" menus to change your settings.
4. Click Save settings.

Changing the locale doesn’t change your language settings in Google Sheets. You can set the language in Google Account settings.

Worked for me :)

Comment: Thank you @Lee Carter for the answer. It worked

Answer (score 1):

`9/18/2004` is not a date. its text string. if you change it to `18/9/2004` then you have a valid date and you can apply your desired formatting

to quickly reformat it you may use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A*1), A2:A, DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, ".{4}$"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^\d+"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "/(\d+)/"))), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

[image]

Comment: depending on locale, `9/18/2004` is a date.. for example USA.

Answer (score 1):

So this just worked for me:

Change settings as advised - but THEN:

1. Insert a new column
2. Copy all dates from the original column into the new on with "paste special" => "values only".
3. Then select all dates and format again as date. From there on I could sort according to date etc.

Answer (score 0):

The formulas seen are kind of complicated, and some of them do not work as expected.
This formula is easy, visual and works for every case:

-First you need to make sure that your dates all have the same length, you can ensure that changing the date format to the one with 0s.

-If your dates are not detected, change the language of the google sheet so that it is, once done that, if you do not like that format you can start converting:

-You just need to take the first two characters, with this:

=Left(A2,2)
(I stored this in L2)

Then you take the mid 2, with this:

=Mid(A2,4,2)
(I stored this in M2)

And just combine them in another cell, like this:

=CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(M2,"/"),L2),RIGHT(A2,5))

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your sheets region to your desired format. This also helps when entering the dates as a text string. Ex: If you entered dd/mm/yy into a USA format it will give you errors.
2. Use =DateValue(A1) in another column. This will change it to a number value.
3. Select the new column and apply the format as you did before.

Comment: Thank you, this worked partially for me, however I have a few BC dates which are represented in normal dd/mm/yyyy format but preceded by a negative '-'. The DateValue(A1) doesn't seem to understand those BC dates. Any ideas?