# Use of DateTime formatted cell in Query in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a registration table with date and name. I want to Query the table to extract the list of names that has the Latest date.

E.g. If I have something like
| Date | Name|
|:---- |:------:|
31/12/2022 | Name1
31/12/2022 | Name2
31/12/2022 | Name3
30/12/2022 | Name4
30/12/2022 | Name5
27/12/2022 | Name6
24/12/2022 | Name7
24/12/2022 | Name8

Then the result of the query would just be

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 31/12/2022 | Name1 |
| 31/12/2022 | Name2 |
| 31/12/2022 | Name3 |

I tried something like
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:B1000, "SELECT A, B WHERE A >= datetime '"&TEXT($A$1,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'",1)

But it doesn't seem to work. Could someone please advise what I should do here? Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Your provided code is working,
it will depend on your set location.

If the location is set in the US for example, the date format should be MM/DD/YYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY *(as your example above)*, that's the reason why you are getting an error.

[image]

[image]

Please see this reference for further explanation:
[Date formatting in Google Sheets is not working according to the instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924433/date-formatting-in-google-sheets-is-not-working-according-to-the-instructions)